Minimum number of pieces of information to uniquely define a polygon
Whilst teaching 'constructing polygons' at school, I was pondering the following question:
What is the fewest number of pieces of information required to construct a unique polygon?
(Note: For this question I will ignore rotations, translations and reflections)
Let me define my terms. Suppose $P$ is an $n$-sided polygon with vertices $V_1, \dots , V_n$.
Define a piece of information to be exactly one of the following:

A length of a specific side. E.g. $V_1V_2 = 4.1cm$
The size of a specific interior angle. E.g. Angle $V_1V_2V_3 = 30^{\circ} $

For example, a triangle can be uniquely defined by three pieces of information (Side, Side, Side). However, three pieces of information cannot guarantee a unique triangle (Angles, Angle, Angle with infinitely many similar triangles)
So my question can be split in to two separate questions:

For a $n$-sided polygon $P$, what is the smallest $k$ such that any $k$ pieces of information  uniquely define $P$?

What is the smallest $k$ such that any $k$ pieces of information guarantee that a unique $n$-sided polygon can be drawn satisfying the given criteria?


My attempt
I have a feeling that the solution may be something to do with 'Folding in corners'.
Consider the following example:

Given these 9 pieces of information, we can form two unique 6-sided polygons by 'folding in a corner'. However I believe that 8 pieces of information can be provided to uniquely define the 6-sided polygon below.

(I have 'prevented any folding of corners' with the information provided with these specific angles)
So it seems that $2n-3$ pieces of information cannot necessarily uniquely define an $n$-sided polygon, but the right $n + \lceil \frac{n}{3} \rceil$ pieces of information can uniquely define a polygon?
This is my intuition but I do not know how to prove it rigorously or whether both these statements are actually correct.

Assume the vertices are listed in cyclic order $V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_n$. Use the first two side lengths and the distance from $V_1$ to $V_3$ to determine a triangle, thus the positions of the first three vertices (up to Euclidean transformation). Thereafter the next side length and interior angle determine the position of the next vertex (relative to that triangle). So you need $3 + 2(n-3) = 2n-3$ pieces of your kind of information.
If you prefer a list containing only lengths you can replace the interior angle at $V_k$ in this list by the length of the segment $V_{k-1}V_{k+1}$.
This construction allows for nonconvex polygons and polygons like stars that self intersect.
Which lists of this kind actually determine a polygon is a harder question. In particular, in this construction the first three lengths in the list must satisfy the triangle inequality.
A more abstract way to reach the same count is to see that locating $n$ points in the plane requires their $2n$ coordinates. Once you have located those points you have three Euclidean "degrees of freedom" to move them as a whole: translations in two directions and a rotation. So the net dimension of the set of configurations of $n$ points is $2n-3$.
In "general position" you always need that many pieces of data. There are special cases for which fewer will do. For example, the quadrilateral with side lengths $1,1,1,3$ consists of four points on a line. There is a precise sense in which the special cases occur with probability $0$.
You might want to read more about geometric rigidity.

I'm slightly unsure as to how your answer demonstrates that every polygon requires at least $2n-3$ pieces of information to uniquely define it. Although I do agree that those specific pieces of information will uniquely define a polygon. Can you prove that for any $2n-2$ (valid) pieces of information, at least two polygons exist?

@Cristof012 See my edit.

I don't think this answers the question.  It does not seem to prove that for every way of choosing $2n-3$ pieces of information, the polygon is uniquely determined.  It argues that there exist some way to choose $2n-3$ pieces of information that uniquely determine the polygon, which is a different result.

@D.W. It's not true that every way of choosing $2n-3$ pieces of information guarantees uniqueness. The answer exhibits one that does. It is true that for general position no way with fewer will do, but I haven't proved that, just offered a heuristic.

@EthanBolker, Thank you for explaining.  That's why I'm suggesting that it doesn't appear to answer the question that was asked, but rather a different question.  It's possible I might have misunderstood something.
